# Will this be sufficient for copying a complete directory to another directory and monitoring the output?

Tags: python, file-transfer, shutil

I am trying to copy over a terabyte of data from one network location to another using the python script below.

```
import shutil
import os
import logging


# logging copy data
def _logpath(path, names):
    logging.info('Working in %s' % path)
    return []   # nothing will be ignored

# path to source directory
src_dir = r'\\networkDrive1\allFolders'

# path to destination directory
dest_dir = r'\\networkDrive2\folder1\folder2\destinationFolder'

# getting all the files in the source directory
files = os.listdir(src_dir)

# copying files
shutil.copytree(src_dir, dest_dir, ignore=_logpath)
```

I am wondering if the code is sufficient to copy the complete directory, including subfolders and I'd like to monitor the output so I know what files are being copied at a given time.

Comment: It would probably be better to use a tool like `rsync`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Windows so rsync isn't an option

Comment: I said "like". I don't use Windows, but surely there are similar applications avaiable for it.

Comment: That said, I don't see why `copytree()` won't do what you want. That's what it's supposed to do, copy a whole directory hierarchy.

Comment: But a standalone application will probably show a progress bar to you.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get Python to show what the current file being copied is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me

```
import shutil
import os
import logging


# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')

# Logging copy progress
def _logpath(path, names):
   logging.info('Copying files from %s' % path)
   logging.info('Files and directories to be copied: %s' % names)
   return []  # nothing will be ignored

# path to source directory
src_dir = r'\\networkDrive1\allFolders'

# path to destination directory
dest_dir = r'\\networkDrive2\folder1\folder2\destinationFolder'

# getting all the files in the source directory
files = os.listdir(src_dir)

# copying files
shutil.copytree(src_dir, dest_dir, ignore=_logpath)
```